# how set 50dp dimension for all android device using android different values folder

Tags: android

I want set height using values/dimens.xml
if i want to set 50dp for values-mdpi/dimens.xml
then how to calculate value for values-hdpi/dimens.xml, values-xhdpi/dimens.xml etc.

If i want to achieve below design for all android device how do I create an XML file and `values/dimens.xml` for all values folder

[image]

Comment: what have you done so far (code)?

Comment: You can use [this](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) lib to do so. It has support for all the android devices.

Answer (score 0):

`50dp` is `50dp` for all screen densities. `dp` stands for "density-independent pixels". So, put `50dp` in `values/dimens.xml`, and you are done.

Comment: i saw some where used
dp = (width in pixels * 160) / screen densityso when would i use this formula

Comment: first of all thank you for reply .... if i had design for tablet where i had container width is 500px so i have question by using this formula can i set dp values for mdpi = 500dp, ldpi = 666dp , hdpi = 333dp, xhdpi = 250dp  is it work with that screen density device

Comment: @rakrin: "dp = (width in pixels * 160) / screen density" -- this converts a value in pixels (`px`) from one density to another. If you size your elements in `dp`, you do not need to do this. "if i had design for tablet where i had container width is 500px" -- ask the designer to design in `dp`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this :
[SDP](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Try this library for perfect design for all devices from small screen to tablet size. You don't need to write dimens file for all screen sizes.